# MapBox addLayer/addSource not adding points from geoJson created from php

Tags: php, json, mapbox, geojson

I'm trying to create a map with points from my geoJson data. Currently the map is not showing any of the points I would like it to look something like this https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/
but with just one color circle (so the properties is not important).

```
var geoJson = <?php echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

map.on('load', function () {
// add source and layer for museums
    map.addSource('points', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: geoJson
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'points',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'points',
        'layout': {
            // make layer visible by default
            'visibility': 'visible'
        },
        'paint': {
        'circle-radius': 3,
        'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
        },
    })
});
```

I know my php works since I used it earlier with what's below and it works fine (creates a bunch of markers but it is too slow and I want circles rather than the default marker shape.)

```
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);


myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
myLayer.on('click', function(e) {
     window.open(e.layer.feature.properties.url);
});
```

Comment: How does your geoJson look like? Could you provide a sample? Also, you seem to be mixing up 2 different libraries: mapbox gl js (your first snippet) and mapbox.js (your second snippet).

Comment: Thanks for this, the issue was I wasn't using mapboxgl.